# How do I find all HTML <span> elements with an attribute foo that equals a value bar?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I've found lots of Nokogiri examples of how to use XPath, or CSS, to find nodes with a particular attribute 'foo'.

I'm not quite getting how to find all the node where a certain attribute equals a certain value.

Specifically, given a HTML doc that might contain multiple instances of:

```
<span class='irrelevant' attrFoo='valueBar'>Some Text</span>
```

How would I find them using Nokogiri?

I thought this would do the trick:

```
doc.xpath("//span[contains(@attrFoo, 'valueBar')]")
```

But it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. The XPath in my question works perfectly. I had the wrong case for the attribute, e.g., it should have used `@attrFoo` but I had `@attrfoo`.